# Смена префикса команды discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Как я могу поменять префикс бота через команду в discord.py? Пробовал использовать этот код, но говорит что не найдена команда setprefix, понимаю что она идёт после bot.run но в коде так и было. Если ставлю её перед bot.run и меняю @commands.command на @bot.command то выдаёт ошибку str object has no attribute guild. Также не понимаю зачем в переменной bot вторым аргументом пишутся три точки. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

custom_prefixes = {}
default_prefixes = ['.']

async def determine_prefix(bot, message):
    guild = message.guild
    if guild:
        return custom_prefixes.get(guild.id, default_prefixes)
    else:
        return default_prefixes

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = determine_prefix, ...)
bot.run(‘токен’)

@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def setprefix(self, ctx, *, prefixes=""):
    custom_prefixes[ctx.guild.id] = prefixes.split() or default_prefixes
    await ctx.send("Prefixes set!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему вы не сделаете через БД, это удобнее и в будущем если ваш бот будет на многих серверах то список не справиться с таким объемом информации

И прочитайте [документацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot) пожалуйста

PostgreSQL

Сначала когда бот заходит на сервер в БД заноситься дефолтний префикс

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_join(self, guild): 
    cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO public."prefixDB" (guild_id, prefix) VALUES ({айди сервера до якого присоединяется бот}, \'дефолтний префикс\');')
    conn.commit()
```

Также когда бот выходит с сервера мы удаляем сервер с БД

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_remove(self, guild):
    cursor.execute(f'DELETE FROM public."prefixDB" WHERE guild_id = {айди сервера от якого отсоединяется бот};')
    conn.commit()
```

Здесь вы заносите перфикс сервера в БД.

```
@commands.command()
@commands.check(is_owner_guild)
async def prefix(self, ctx, prefix):
    guildid = ctx.guild.id
    cursor.execute(f'UPDATE public."prefixDB" SET prefix=\'{prefix}\' WHERE guild_id = \'{guildid}\';')# здесь вы обновляете префикс сервера
    conn.commit()
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Выполнено успешно!', description=f'Префикс сервера изменений на "** {prefix} **"', colour= discord.Color.green(), timestamp= ctx.message.created_at)
    emb.set_footer(text=ctx.message.author)
    await ctx.send(embed= emb)

@prefix.error
async def prefix_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        emb = discord.Embed(timestamp= ctx.message.created_at, title='Ошибка!!!', colour=discord.Color.red(), description='Эту команду может использовать только владелец сервера')
        emb.set_footer(text= ctx.message.author)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

После просто через функцию забираете его:

```
def get_prefix(bot, message):
   guildid = message.guild.id #айди сервера где была визвана команда prefix
   cursor.execute(f'SELECT prefix FROM public."prefixDB" WHERE guild_id = \'{guildid}\';')
   prefix = cursor.fetchone()
   conn.commit()

   return prefix

bot =commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix, help_command=None)
```

Comment: Приведите пример или/и какую-то другую конкретную информацию, как "сделать через БД"

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй через такие команды:

```py
# Использование одного префикса
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$') # $ - префикс

# Если использован префикс по умолчанию или префикс !
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!")) # ! - префикс
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как грамотно нужно это делать, но у меня был костыль вроде смены значения `command_prefix` у `bot` в ивенте `on_message`:

```
async def on_message(message):
    prefix = ...  # Здесь ты получаешь префикс бота на сервере
    bot.command_prefix = prefix
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```