# Смена префикса командой для каждого сервера на Sqlite3 Discord.py

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

Видел вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1124738/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-discord-py) как этого сделали на PostgreSQL.
Хотелось бы понять как это сделать на Sqlite 3.
Я в Sql новичок, поэтому прошу помощи тут.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Такая самая схема.

Answer (score 0):

```
async def get_prefix(bot, message):
    extras = await prefixes_for(message.guild) # returns a list
    return commands.when_mentioned_or(*extras)(bot, message)
```

[источник](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#prefix-helpers)